# RubyOnRails, ActiveScaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, activescaffold

I work with active scaffold

Table has many data so pagination is actually for this case.

In table printed data about companies if I check one - so we see in table only this one. User's checking - saved in session variable.

Occasionally after I go to other page suddenly i see data about other company.

Seems that session was lost or changed

May anyone had same problem.

```
class TLForConfirmController < ApplicationController
    layout 'application'
    before_action :update_as_config
    active_scaffold :tl do |config|
      #config.sti_children = :tl_change
      FIRST_PART_COLUMNS=   [:id_org_by_year,:organization_name, :start_date,:end_date]
      SECOND_PART_FIRST_HALF_COLUMNS=[:tl_short_type_first_half,:main_subject_first_half,:day_of_week_first_half]
      SECOND_PART_SECOND_HALF_COLUMNS=[:tl_short_type,:main_subject,:day_of_week]

      config.list.per_page = 100

      config.columns[:id_org_by_year].set_link(link_for_association(config.columns[:tl_changes]))
    end

    def self.reflect_on_all_associations
        TL.reflect_on_all_associations
    end

    def  conditions_for_collection // here attached session[:act_organization] to question
        sql_filter=''
        if  !session[:tl_status].blank? and session[:tl_status].to_s.to_i!=Activity::STATUS_DELETED and  session[:act_id].to_i==0
          sql_filter=' activity_status_id in ('+ session[:tl_status].join(',')+ ')'
        end
        # logger.info "    check session ----------> " + session[:act_organization].inspect
        if !session[:act_organization].blank? and session[:act_organization][0]>0 
            unless sql_filter.empty?
              sql_filter=sql_filter+' and '
            end
            sql_filter=sql_filter+'organization_id in ( '+(Array session[:act_organization]).to_a.join(',')+ ')'
        end
        unless sql_filter.empty?
            ['('+sql_filter+')']
        end
    end
end
```

list_to_confirm.html.erb:

```
<%if @sql_filter.empty?%>
<%= render :active_scaffold => 'tl_for_confirm',
:params => {:file_time => Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")},:locals => {:file_time1 => Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")} %>
<%else%>
<%= render :active_scaffold => 'tl_for_confirm', :conditions => @sql_filter , :params => {:file_time => Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")} %>
<% end %>
```

Controller: tl_controller.rb

```
TLController< ApplicationController
    def search_results // here code sends after Submit for define sesions
        if request.post?

        if !params[:search][:organization_id].blank?
            session[:act_organization]=get_array_codes_for_search(params[:search][:organization_id].to_a.collect { |item| item.to_i })
            logger.info " search_results " + session[:act_organization].inspect
        else
            session[:act_organization]=nil
        end
        end
    end

    def  list_to_confirm
    end

end

def get_array_codes_for_search(arr_code)
    rez=[]

     unless arr_code.blank?
      if arr_code[0].kind_of?(Array)
        arr_code = arr_code[0] 
      end
      if arr_code.kind_of?(String)  
        arr_code = (Array arr_code) 
      end

      unless arr_code.size==0
          arr_code.delete_if{|c| c.to_i<=0||c.to_s.empty? }
          res = arr_code.map{|i| i.to_i}
      end
     end
   return res

end
```

PS

1. I check log file: its indeed sudenly "take" other value for company.
2. At controller in action any same value(number)
3. So there is 2-files with config:

   - session_store.rb :
     `Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :key     => '_my_app_session'`
   - new_framework_defaults.rb:

This file contains migration options to ease your Rails 5.0 upgrade.

Read the Rails 5.0 release notes for more info on each option.

Enable per-form CSRF tokens. Previous versions had false.

```
Rails.application.config.action_controller.per_form_csrf_tokens = true
```

Enable origin-checking CSRF mitigation. Previous versions had false.
    Rails.application.config.action_controller.forgery_protection_origin_check = true

Make Ruby 2.4 preserve the timezone of the receiver when calling `to_time`.
Previous versions had false.

```
ActiveSupport.to_time_preserves_timezone = true
```

Require `belongs_to` associations by default. Previous versions had false.

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
```

Do not halt callback chains when a callback returns false. Previous versions had true.

```
ActiveSupport.halt_callback_chains_on_return_false = false
```

Configure SSL options to enable HSTS with subdomains. Previous versions had   false.

```
Rails.application.config.ssl_options = { hsts: { subdomains: true } }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's very difficult to debug code that you have described verbally. Please *edit your question* and add in: the models you have talked about, the controller action you mention, the "table printed data about companies" that you mention, also wherever the company goes into session.

Comment: Code was added
May be you see it with fresh eye

Comment: In future... can you please: 1) indent your code in your Stack Overflow questions (and don't indent non-code). This means we can separate out the code and the non-code ahnd it is much easier to read your question. If your question is hard to read, we don't want to read it and are less likely to help you... it's good courtesy, when asking for help, to make it easy for us to help you. 2) use *spaces* not tabs to indent your code - everybody has their tab-stops set up differently to you. spaces are the ruby/rails Best Practice. Use 2 spaces for each indentation-level after the first

Comment: When do you set `params[:search][:organization_id]` ? Where is the code for that?

Comment: This is parameters we got from form
search_result it after submit function
PS thank you for tips :)

Comment: Can you please show the code? Also show for `get_array_codes_for_search` - because these things are the parts that find the organization that then gets set in the session, right?

Comment: its clear from empty and zero

Comment: erk... code in comments is awful and impossible to read (as you can see). Can you please edit your question and always put code snippets there? :)